# Is it possible to track kilometers covered in realtime using flutter?

Tags: flutter, location

I have been working on a ride sharing app in flutter, I have managed to track location of user but now I need the app to record the kilometers covered by the user as they move around.

I have tried subtracting the distance from the starting point but it seems to decrease the total distance when someone moves backward, what's the best I can go about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding the displacement, not the distance with this approach.
Try implementing conditions in case the user starts travelling backwards to increment and not decrement in the case of calculating the total distance.

You can alternatively try out the:

[Distance Matrix API which is a part of the Google Maps platform.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)